# Map crashes when I zoom to an extent that is too far east

Tags: javascript, zooming, extent

I've got a map with a button that zooms to the extent of a feature. It works fine most of the time but when the extent is too far east the entire map dissapears.

This is what I've got in javascript:

```
function initMap() {

  var view = new ol.View({
    center: endpoint,
    zoom: 4,
    maxZoom: 16,
  });

  map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers:[],
    view: view
  });

  map.addControl(zoomToExtentControl);
};


zoomToExtentControl = new ol.control.ZoomToExtent({
 extent: [-1013450.0281739295, 3594671.9021477713, 6578887.117336057, 10110775.689402476],
  className: 'custom-zoom-extent',
  label: 'Z'
});
```

and later in another function:

```
 let xMinMax = ol.proj.fromLonLat([xMin, xMax]);
 let yMinMax = ol.proj.fromLonLat([yMin, yMax]);
 let padding = 1.06;
 zoomToExtentControl.extent = [(xMinMax[0] * padding), (yMinMax[0] * (padding-0.02)), (xMinMax[1] * padding), (yMinMax[1] * padding)];
```

Why does the map crash when the extent is in the east but work fine when its not? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the xMinMax/yMinMax calculation, ol.proj.fromLonLat input is a coordinate as longitude and latitude, i.e. an array with longitude as 1st and latitude as 2nd element. It seems you are using two longitudes or two latitudes (I read two x and two y).